# How do query notifications detect changes in the query result?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-broker

I am working with a legacy database that has implemented query notifications against a table called *ColorList*.

While running a server-side trace for an unrelated issue, I noticed the query

```
SELECT color FROM ColorList
```

was being executed **every 10 milliseconds**.

Is this how Query Notification works? Does SQL Server store the results of the original query and then run the query endlessly until it detects a change?

Comment: Don't get to used to using notification services.  It's only available in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read [the Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) for an explanation on how it works. If you see the query executed every 10ms it means your *application* is running it every 10ms. My [8 ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_8-Ball) is telling me your code does not check the notification [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.aspx) and is blindly resubmitting the query despite the [Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationinfo.aspx) being of the value `Invalid`, indicating a query than cannot be notified. Which is to be expected, since your query does not conform to the [Query Notification restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx):

> The projected columns in the SELECT statement must be explicitly
>   stated, and **table names must be qualified with two-part names**.